# PHP using phpSPO with Sharepoint ; How to create folder in a subsite

Tags: php, sharepoint

I'm working with phpSPO library for work with sharePooint in a PHP app. https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO

I am using the following code to successfully create a folder in the Shared Documents folder on Sharepoint:

```
<?php

    spl_autoload_register(function ($classname) {
        $classname = ltrim($classname, "\\");
        preg_match('/^(.+)?([^\\\\]+)$/U', $classname, $match);
        $classname = './'.str_replace("\\", "/", $match[1])
            .str_replace(array("\\", "_"), "/", $match[2])
            .".php";
        include_once $classname;
    });

    use Office365\Runtime\Auth\ClientCredential;
    use Office365\SharePoint\ClientContext;
    use Office365\SharePoint\Web;

    $credentials = new ClientCredential("MyClientId", "MyClientSecret");
    $ctx = (new ClientContext("https://MyDomain.sharepoint.com"))->withCredentials($credentials);

    $folderName = "TestFolder_" . rand(1, 100000);
    $rootFolder = $ctx->getWeb()->getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("Shared Documents");
    $newFolder = $rootFolder->getFolders()->add($folderName)->executeQuery();
    print($newFolder->getServerRelativeUrl());
```

?>

That creates the folder in the 'Shared Documents' folder. However My client has created a sub-site called 'Enquiries'. I cannot work out how to create a folder within the 'Shared Documents' folder of the subsite.

For the life of me I cannot seem to track down a root path.

I am not sure whether I am missing something fundamental about sharepoint (this is my first exposure to Sharepoint)

How do I find the path to it to add it?

Is there another way within the phpSPO framework for adding folders to a specific site/subsite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was (in the end) simple:
Change the ClientContext to include the Site Name/Subsite Name.

In this case my subsite was called 'enquiries'.

```
<?php

    spl_autoload_register(function ($classname) {
        $classname = ltrim($classname, "\\");
        preg_match('/^(.+)?([^\\\\]+)$/U', $classname, $match);
        $classname = './'.str_replace("\\", "/", $match[1])
            .str_replace(array("\\", "_"), "/", $match[2])
            .".php";
        include_once $classname;
    });


    use Office365\Runtime\Auth\ClientCredential;
    use Office365\SharePoint\ClientContext;
    use Office365\SharePoint\SiteUrl;
    use Office365\SharePoint\Web;

    $credentials = new ClientCredential("MyClientId", "MyClientSecret");
    $ctx = (new ClientContext("https://MyDomain.sharepoint.com/enquiries"))->withCredentials($credentials);


    $folderName = "Spencer_" . rand(1, 100000);
    $rootFolder = $ctx->getWeb()->getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("Shared Documents");
    $newFolder = $rootFolder->getFolders()->add($folderName)->executeQuery();
    print($newFolder->getServerRelativeUrl());

?>
```

I had been trying to find a relative path from Root but that always threw an error.
The answer was to change the root.