# Upload csv file to SharePoint using PHP Laravel

Tags: php, sharepoint-2013, laravel-7

I am referring the steps mentioned here [phpSPO](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO) to include the library first in my php application using command `composer require vgrem/php-spo`.  But when using below code to create a client, is not working for me. I am receiving all the client attributes as `null`.

```
  use Office365\Runtime\Auth\ClientCredential;
  use Office365\SharePoint\ClientContext;

  $credentials = new ClientCredential("{clientId}", "{clientSecret}");
  $ctx = (new ClientContext("{siteUrl}"))->withCredentials($credentials);
```

If anyone faced the same issue and got it fixed then please guide me as well.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed this post and I was able to resolve this issue. Thank you.
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67861925/php-using-phpspo-with-sharepoint-how-to-create-folder-in-a-subsite`